# Can a mod restore a user's self deleted answers en masse?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, deleted-answers

While going through old questions I keep coming across answers by [this user](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/412/none). As the remaining answers would suggest, they are generally at least of a decent quality, and many are very good. The problem is that they are all deleted.

In my opinion, their answers are typically good enough to worth preserving for posterity. So I've been voting undelete whenever I see one, for the past month or so. But I don't think it is doing any good, and I don't think many other people were likely to stumble upon them either. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be any way to search for these deleted answers (at least, by a normal user like me).

Has anyone else noticed this, and do people think these answers should be restored? Would a moderator be able to restore these answers in bulk?

---

What I've found so far:

- [Why did Canada, Australia and New Zealand separate from UK?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1793/4935)
- [Why Napoleon was not executed or imprisoned?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1767/4935)
- [At what point did mapmaking begin to accurately reflect what we now know about the earth?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/2561/4935)
- [Why did the United States not seriously develop Anti Aircraft Missiles?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/928/4935)
- [How did people acquire things in the pre-Roman Celtic world?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/3218/4935)
- [What were the reasons for the Renaissance / scientific revolution in Europe?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1034/4935)
- [Who kept noble prisoners captured in battle?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/7801/4935)
- [Why was language not used to establish dominance throughout England 1066 AD–1360s CE?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/2919/4935)
- [Why Canada failed to emerge as a power like UK or France?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1787/4935)
- [Were there historical examples of “citizen's arrest” concept in history independent of British common law?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1056/4935)
- [Has a book ever caused the ousting of a dictator?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1530/4935)
- [How well can cavalry fight infantry?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/1154/4935)

---

**After a week, it seems like no one is opposed to this. Can a mod weigh in?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on LF's answer and his upvoters, I've gone in and restored all the answers linked.

Personally, I don't think they are really up to this stack's current standards (eg: there isn't a single hyperlink among them). If I were an individual voter, I doubt I would have voted to restore more than one or two of them.

However, that's my personal belief. The community can now decide on them.

Answer (score 3):

They are all accepted and high voted; some very highly for beta site volume.

Since content is more important than user existentialism: **Yes**, I believe they should be restored on en masse; in alignment with the site's *[cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)* license.

Providing other members agree.